# Getting a "Call to a member function function() on a non-object" error in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, php

I'm very new to CodeIgniter and not an expert in OOP so please bear with me.

This is the function I have in my model:

```
function get_company(int $user_id, $fields = '*'){
    $r = $this->db->query("SELECT $fields FROM ".$this->db->dbprefix('companies')." WHERE user_id=?", $user_id)->row();
    return $r;        
}
function get_profile($user_id, $fields = '*'){
    $r = $this->db->query("SELECT $fields FROM ".$this->db->dbprefix('users_profiles')." WHERE user_id=?", $user_id)->row();
    return $r;        
}
```

This is in my controller that is calling that model:

```
function index(){ 
    $this->load->model('profiles_m');
    $profile = $this->profiles_m->get_profile($this->access->getUid());
    $company = $this->profile_m->get_company($this->access->getUid());      

    $vars = array(
            'profile'=>$profile, 
            'company'=>$company,        
        );

    $this->_getTemplate()->build('account', $vars);
}
```

An in my view:

```
$company = array(
        'name'     => 'company',
        'id'          => 'company',
        'value'       => "$company->name",
        'class'       => 'styl_f validate[required] text-input input-xlarge',
        'placeholder' => "$company->name"
);

echo $company['value']
```

The error I am getting is this: `Call to a member function get_company() on a non-object in C:\..\application\modules\accounts\controllers\accounts.php`
I am under the impression that I am receiving these errors because I am passing a non object through get_company() but the thing that confuses me is that this error does not come up for get_profile(); The get_profile() function in my model is very similiar to my get_company() function. What is causing this error? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within your controller:

```
function index(){ 
    $this->load->model('profiles_m');
    $profile = $this->profiles_m->get_profile($this->access->getUid());
    $company = $this->profile_m->get_company($this->access->getUid()); // Right here

    $vars = array(
            'profile'=>$profile, 
            'company'=>$company,        
        );

    $this->_getTemplate()->build('account', $vars);
}
```

The $profile variable uses `$this->profiles_m` as the object, but $company misses the letter 's' in the object.

Try with this line instead:

```
    $company = $this->profiles_m->get_company($this->access->getUid());
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot.

EDIT: You also forgot the s in your answer!

Comment: @Xecure Do'h... Theres - I fixed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, the line should read:

```
$company = $this->profiles_m->get_company($this->access->getUid());
```

Notice 'profiles_m' and not 'profile_m'.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $company = $this->profile_m->get_company($this->access->getUid());
```

replace 'profile_m' to 'profiles_m'